# Assign result of UNIX command to a variable

Tags: unix, date-conversion

I am trying to convert the date format in UNIX, the format is getting converted but unable to assign it to a variable.

```
DATE=20200520
A=date -d"$DATE" +%Y\-%m\-%d
-bash: -d20200501: command not found
```

`date -d"$DATE" +%Y\-%m\-%d` This is properly working, but when assigned to variable it's failing.

I tried assigning using `A = $(date -d"$DATE" +%Y\-%m\-%d)` symbol as well, still it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use $ symbol when assigning the result of another command to a variable.

```
A=$(date -d"$DATE" +%Y\-%m\-%d)
```

There is a space in between A and = symbol and $ symbol, that is the reason it failed while using $ symbol

[image]